# Shapefile DBF Editing in Stata for ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, editing, stata

I am trying to edit shapefile in ArcMap.

How I can keep or clean some information from shapefile in ArcMap?

In my shapefile, I have information about street type such as road, route, highway, street, expressway,... I just want to use road and highway and I want to remove other street type information. This is the file: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/RNF-FRR/index-eng.cfm

I used DBF file extension to work with Excel, then I import Excel file in Stata to clean my data. (I used this command: keep if type == "RD" | type =="HWY" ). After cleaning process, I import CSV Excel file into ArcMap, then I tried to convert CSV file to shapefile. But, I could not create network dataset.

Comment: You need to tell us more about what you mean by "edit". Are you trying to remove some features from the shapefile? Are you trying to change the geometry of existing features?

Comment: Have a read of https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Adding_the_Editor_toolbar/01m600000043000000/ and https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m60000002v000000 and some of the related documents, this sounds like what you're after.

Comment: **Don't save from Excel** it will break the dbf file. If you want to remove everything *except* Type = 'RD' or Type = 'HWY' in ArcMap then use select by attributes on the layer with the query not (Type = 'RD' or Type = 'HWY' ) and then either press delete in an edit session or execute the Delete Features tool https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000036000000 which will remove the selected features... be sure to keep a backup though. Creating a network dataset should be a 2nd question, please address that in a new thread; do you have a Network Analyst license?

Comment: Thank you so much!! Actually, what I am trying to do is that I have CSD coordinates and Border coordinates for Canada, I want to see which roads can be used to go from origin to destination points. (For instance: from Toronto to Vancouver, which roads can be used to arrive in Vancouver   with / without crossing border) I want to see this network in ArcMap. Thus, I am trying to combine those 3  file, do you think that can I combine CSD cordinates and Border coordinates with Road network file to have what I am trying to do obtain ? @MichaelStimson

Comment: Yes, I have license. @MichaelStimson

Comment: To build a geometric network you need to import your shapefile into a geodatabase (personal, file or enterprise) feature dataset... there is a tutorial https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00470000005t000000 which covers the highlights. Note that there are two entities that sound *very* similar but have different properties/abilities: Network Dataset and Geometric Network, read more about geometric networks https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002r00000001000000

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am unsure whether I am using right shapefile or not (road network file). I am getting so complicated map. @MichaelStimson

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the file directly in ArcMap. Load the shapefile into ArcMap, then right click on the new layer and select "Open Attribute Table". In the attribute table click on the button in the top left (Options) and click "Select by Attributes". This will open a new dialog where you can write a selection query. Yours will be something like

```
  "type" = 'RD' OR "type" = 'HWY'
```

Watch out for double vs. single quotes. Double are used for field names, single for values. You can select the field names from the dialog box which will provide the right quoting. Likewise, you can click "Get Unique Values" to see the possible values. Click on a value and it will be entered in the query with the right quotes. Once your query is written, click on "Apply". The relevant entries will be highlighted in the attribute table.

Dismiss the 'Select by Attributes" dialog and return to the map view. Right click on the layer and select "Export". Select "Export Selected Features", pick the coordinate system you want (original layer vs. dataframe), and set the output location and type (probably want to save back as new shapefile). Click OK and you're done.

Comment: You don't need the double quotes or square brackets for a selection where clause. type = 'RD' OR type = 'HWY' will work for shapefiles, file geodatabase, personal geodatabase... the delimiting of field names for selection SQL statements adds unneeded complexity.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - thanks for pointing this out. I'm so used to just clicking the field names and having ArcMap add it with double quotes that I had forgotten that the quotes are option.